# Dynamically Sort by lambda expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I m doing sorting in my application as shown below .

```
public IQueryable<Users> SelectAll(string sSortExpression, string sSortOrder)
{
    if (sSortOrder == "asc")
    {
        switch (sSortExpression)
        {
            case "FirstName":
                return UsersRepository.Entities.OrderBy(x => x.FirstName);
            case "LastName":
                return UsersRepository.Entities.OrderBy(x => x.LastName);
            default:
                return UsersRepository.Entities.OrderBy(x => x.Id);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        switch (sSortExpression)
        {
            case "FirstName":
                return UsersRepository.Entities.OrderByDescending(x => x.FirstName);
            case "LastName":
                return UsersRepository.Entities.OrderByDescending(x => x.LastName);
            default:
                return UsersRepository.Entities.OrderByDescending(x => x.UserName);
        }
    }
}
```

Its fine now , but I have to sort on all fields in `Users` table (**Around 30 fields** ) .
Then the method will be very big

I tried using reflections like this

```
public IQueryable<Users> SelectAll(string sSortExpression, string sSortOrder)
{
    var _property = UsersRepository.GetType().GetProperties().Where(a => a.Name == sSortExpression);
    if (sSortOrder == "asc")
    {
        return UsersRepository.Entities.OrderBy(x => _property);
    }
    else
    {
        return UsersRepository.Entities.OrderByDescending(x => _property);
    }
}
```

But faild.

Is there any better way to do this ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to go: change your method to accept `Expression` instead of `string`:

```
public IQueryable<Users> SelectAll<TProp>(Expression<Func<Users, TProp>> selector, string sSortOrder)
{
    if (sSortOrder == "asc")
    {
        return UsersRepository.Entities.OrderBy(selector);
    }
    else
    {
        return UsersRepository.Entities.OrderByDescending(selector);
    }
}
```

You can call it as:

```
SelectAll(x => x.LastName, "asc");
```

Or if you really need it to be string, you have to generate Expression Tree using `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression` class method:

```
public IQueryable<Users> SelectAll<TProp>(string sSortExpression, string sSortOrder)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Users));
    var propExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Users, TProp>>(Expression.Property(param, sSortExpression), param);

    if (sSortOrder == "asc")
    {
        return UsersRepository.Entities.OrderBy(propExpression);
    }
    else
    {
        return UsersRepository.Entities.OrderByDescending(propExpression);
    }
}
```

But it will require to specify generic type parameter on `SelectAll` call:

```
var results = SelectAll<int>("Id", "asc");
```

Comment: TProp : type namespace could not found

Comment: Have you changed the method declaration to contain `<TProp>` generic parameter?

Comment: What about Nested Objects sorting, For example OrderBy(o=> o.City.Name) ?

Answer (score 3):

You can create your expression for sorting like

```
public IQueryable<Users> SelectAllByCompany(string sSortExpression, string sSortOrder)
{
    var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Users),"u");
    var sortExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<User,object>>(Expresion.Property(p,sSortExpression), p);

    if (sSortOrder == "asc")
    {
        return UsersRepository.Entities.OrderBy(sortExpr);
    }
    else
    {
        return UsersRepository.Entities.OrderByDescending(sortExpr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this extension method:

```
public static IQueryable<TEntity> OrderBy<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> source, string orderByProperty,
                      bool desc)
    {
        string command = desc ? "OrderByDescending" : "OrderBy";
        var type = typeof(TEntity);
        var property = type.GetProperty(orderByProperty);
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
        var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
        var orderByExpression = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);
        var resultExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), command, new Type[] { type, property.PropertyType },
                                      source.Expression, Expression.Quote(orderByExpression));
        return source.Provider.CreateQuery<TEntity>(resultExpression);
    }
```

Then use Users.OrderBy(sSortExpression, true if descending, false if ascending)

Comment: This is a much better way of doing it. Generic logic.